# Ubuntu 20.04.4 version can't detect wifi networks

Tags: networking, wireless

Ubuntu is not detecting WiFi networks. I'm using the same adapter for windows 11 on same computer(dual boot), and it's working fine. I've updated everything and tried a few methods from google and YouTube, but couldn't fix the problem. I'm new in Ubuntu.

[No Networks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRgff.png)

Comment: Please run ifconfig in your cli (command line interface) and paste the results in your question.